# Android Studio Relative Layout does not fill the screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I think relative layout is a very powerful utility for designing a user interface because it can eliminate nested view groups and keep your layout hierarchy flat, which improves performance. However I used relative layout for my Android app recently. The problem is that it can't fill the screen. how can I solve the problem? Relative layout does not support weight or gravity? Do I need to using linear layout for that? Is there any solution for that? thank you for your kind answer.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/picturelayout">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/binanceprofittrace" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@color/Teal"
            android:id="@+id/buyLayout"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/picturelayout">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buyPriceText"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Buy price" />

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/buyPriceID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:hint="Enter your bid price"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quentityText"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buyPriceText"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="Quentity" />

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quentityID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buyPriceID"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:hint="Enter your quentity"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/totalAmountButtonID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quentityText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="caulculate TOTAL AMOUNT"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalAmountResultD"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quentityID"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:id="@+id/PrecentageLayout"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/buyLayout">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profitRateText"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:text="Enter profit rate %" />
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/profitRateID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:hint="Enter profit percentage"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/percentageBnbButtonID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:text="trade with bnb"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profitRateText"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/percentageBtcButtonID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profitRateID"
            android:text="trade with btc/eth/usdt"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentageBnbResult"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/percentageBnbButtonID"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentageBtcResult"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/percentageBtcButtonID"
            android:textColor="@color/Teal"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@color/Teal"
            android:id="@+id/sellLayout"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/PrecentageLayout">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selltRateText"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="Enter sell price" />
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sellRateID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:hint="Enter sell price"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/sellBnbButtonID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:text="trade with bnb"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/selltRateText"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/sellBtcButtonID"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sellRateID"
            android:text="trade with btc/eth/usdt"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellBnbResult"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sellBnbButtonID"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellBtcResult"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sellBtcButtonID"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellBnbPercentage"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sellBnbResult"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellBtcPercentage"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sellBtcResult"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes you can't use layout_gravity or weights with relative layout.You have to use Linear layout or Frame layout to achieve what you are trying as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me as the second activity and played a video in full screen 
added no title bar in manifests

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlayVideo">


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```